# Restrict user form accessing page in React app

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt, authorization

I am a beginner to software development. I am trying to build a React web application which will be used at a clinic. Currently the application will have only two users. In the application, patients will input data using a single form and doctors will be able to see the data on his/her dashboard. I don't want the user to access the doctor's dashboard therefore I want to restrict his access to the form submission. Also only the doctor will have credentials, as he/she will be the owner of the application. Kindly guide me on how should I proceed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your current project looks like. From the tags `express` and `jwt` I assume you're using express to serve the pages to your users so could you share some of the code you have already produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep your logged in user detail into reducer, so you can able to identify loggedin user is patient or doctor

add conditional component if user is doctor then show doctor dashboard

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { withRouter, Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
import { compose } from "recompose";

class formContainer extends SignUp {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="mid-container">
                {
                    this.props.userData.type == "DOCTOR" ?
                        <DoctorDashboard/> // if user is doctor then show doctor dashboard 
                        :
                        <PatientDashboard/>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        // save your login user data in react redux
        userData: state.login.userData  //  here is your userdata of loggedin user, here you can identify is logged in user is patient or doctor if not keep user type like patient or doctor
    }
}

export default compose(
    withRouter,
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(formContainer)
```